# Querying the entry for an HTTP Referer

Tags: entries

`craft.request.urlReferrer` returns the full URL of the referrer, while `craft.entries.uri` accepts the URI only.

Do I need to split the URL just to get URI path, write a twig filter, a custom plugin?

Maybe I can’t see the forest for the trees, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: I don't see how you can query an entry for URLs which link to an entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)  Are you looking for craft.request.url ?   What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My use case is fairly convoluted, but ultimately, I'm spoofing the "active" page in my navigation to be the referring page to the entry. It's not mission critical, but a nice consistency feature for the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom Twig filter, per Michael's suggestion.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_Filter_Method;

class BusinessLogicTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'pathFromUrl' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'pathFromUrl')
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return Craft::t('Path From URL Extension');
    }

    public function pathFromUrl($url)
    {
        return ltrim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
    }
}
```

Add that to a plugin, and add the `addTwigExtension` method to your main plugin file, for example:

```
public function addTwigExtension() {
    Craft::import('plugins.businesslogic.twigextensions.BusinessLogicTwigExtension');
    return new BusinessLogicTwigExtension();
}
```

You can then use the filter with `craft.entries.uri` and `craft.request.urlReferrer` to obtain the entry for the referring page.

```
{% set referringEntry = craft.entries.uri(craft.request.urlReferrer|pathFromUrl).first() %}
```

Answer (score 2):

No obvious solution sticks out to me using only native Twig functions/filters.

It'd be pretty trivial to write a custom filter using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), though...

Comment: Thats not a super helpful answer.

Comment: Seems like it was helpful enough to nudge the thread towards a [nice solution](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16665/689)...  :-)